# How to get rid of Desktop Manager beside the project name when creating new projects in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, project

When I create new Project in Eclipse, it displays the Desktop Manager beside the project name by default. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

**If** I understand your problem correctly, you're seeing the file location next to the file name.  It looks something like this, perhaps?
[image: project tagged with location]

There are a handful of ways to get rid of the location tag, but the most correct one (the one Eclipse *wants* you to use) is for you to put the project in the default location.

[image: project in default location]

That results in a project name having no location tag.  It also helps Eclipse find your projects later.

[image]

*A caveat: since I do not have a screenshot of your problem and I do not know which Eclipse version you are using, nor what compoents you've added, I might be thinking of the wrong tag.  If so, please add those details and I'll continue trying to help.*